# How to fit a 1600px x 1600px Image to EditText as android:background

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm trying to fit a  1600px x 1600px image in an `EditText`.
I tried many combinations of  `android:padding` but none seems to work

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background=""
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.116" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="296dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ButtonLogin"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="57dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="229dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> This is what i get when i put the Image as an `android:background`

[image: Issue]

**This is my goal:**

[image: My Goal]

Is there any way of doing this **in this specific XML** or do i have to change the Image's **Resolution**?

Comment: Where is your `EditText`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** 
     to achieve your goal you should use EditText not ImageView.
     (You've to add EditText in your .xml)

Here is the **way to achieve your goal**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="26dp"
        android:background="#3F4650"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:textColorHint="#636A72"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**create xml file** in app > res > drawable > ic_person.xml for the person image in EditText **or** you can also use different image just change android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_other_image"

```
<vector 
    android:height="72dp" 
    android:tint="#CED0CF"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0" 
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:width="72dp" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <path 
            android:fillColor="#FF000000" 
            android:pathData="M12,12c2.21,0 4,-1.79 4,-4s-1.79,-4 -4,-4 -4,1.79 -4,4 1.79,4 4,4zM12,14c-2.67,0 -8,1.34 -8,4v2h16v-2c0,-2.66 -5.33,-4 -8,-4z"/>
</vector>
```

[[ OUTPUT ]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1Z7F.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make a LinearLayout as parent. Make the gravity:horizontal, and add an ImageView and EditText.

Something like:

```
<LinearLayout>
<ImageView/>
<EditText/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Make the width of the `ImageView` match the height of the `LinearLayout` to achieve square shape, and you should be all set.

Good luck!